# Angularjs trying to watch a property of an object in an array

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

```
$scope.testObj = [{'name':'john'},{'name':'bob'}];
```

In this case I do

```
$scope.watch(testObj.name, examplefunction, true)....
```

this does not work but this does

```
$scope.watch(testObj[0].name...)
```

The former stops the page from completely loading, am I doing this wrong? I read a bunch of stackoverflow examples that used the same syntax. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to save the object to the database before sending it off to another module, when a user finishes editing a certain cell in ng-grid(name in this example).

Comment: `$scope.watch('testObj[0].name', …`

Comment: I dont want to watch just the first index though I want to watch them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved here. See if this works for you.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/choroshin/2014/03/26/angularjs-watch-for-changes-in-specific-object-property/

Here is a JSFiddle with example

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.count=0;
    $scope.people = [{id:1,name: "bill"}, {id:2,name: "jim"}, {id:3,name: "ryan"}]

    $scope.$watch(function($scope) {
      return $scope.people.
          map(function(obj) {
            return obj.name
          });
}, function (newVal) {
        $scope.count++;
        $scope.msg = 'person name was changed'+newVal;
    }, true);


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/byws7/28/